# Initialise template within derived constructor initialisation list

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initializer-list

Foo inherits `std::array<int, 2>`. Is it possible to fill the array in the initialiser list of Foo's constructor?

If so what would be a valid alternative to the below syntax?

```
// Foo is always an array of 2 ints
struct Foo: std::array<int, 2>
{
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const int & x, const int & y) : std::array<int, 2> { x, y } {}
}
```

I tried adding an extra pair of braces, which works on g++, however not on the VC2015 compiler:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo : std::array<int, 2>
{
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const int & x, const int & y) : std::array<int, 2> {{ x, y }} {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo(5, 12);

    std::cout << foo[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo[1] << std::endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

and got the following errors: https://i.gyazo.com/4dcbb68d619085461ef814a01b8c7d02.png

Comment: Why does `Foo` inherit from `std::array`?

Comment: In my app it will be a point/vector class with GetX() SetY() functions etc. To me this makes more sense than a struct with x,y,z data members because it allows me to remove repeated code for each dimension.

Comment: It's certainly up to you on how you design things.  But I will say that inheritance is not the best tool for most jobs ( http://blog.codinghorror.com/inherits-nothing/ , and, unlike C#, most of the C++ standard library isn't really designed to be inherited from).  While you can inherit from `std::array`, note that it has no `virtual` functions, meaning that you will almost never interact with your `Foo` through a `std::array` pointer or reference; but that's OK because `std::array`'s destructor is nonvirtual, so so you need to know you really have a `Foo` when you destroy your object.

Comment: But without any `virtual` methods in the base class, I personally don't see much reason to use inheritance.

Comment: What's the best alternative? I'm trying to avoid C arrays.

Comment: "Favour composition over inheritance" I guess. So will it be fine if I just make the array a member of foo?

Comment: Again, you're free to do what you want.  I would recommend using composition.  I think it often makes sense to have a similar interface to `std::array` (e.g., `begin()`, `end()`, `size()`), but the experts no longer recommend using inheritance to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you just need an extra pair of braces:

```
struct Foo: std::array<int, 2> {
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const int & x, const int & y) : std::array<int, 2> {{ x, y }} {}
                                                           ^        ^
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28850e71b272380a)

For VC++ compiler you'll need a pair of parentheses instead of braces:

```
struct Foo : std::array<int, 2> {
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const int & x, const int & y) : std::array<int, 2>({ x, y }) {}
                                                          ^        ^
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work; please see my edited question.

EDIT: In VS2015

Comment: Thanks! Your latest edit works fine. Marking as solved.